# Is it ok to view Time Machine backup directly and store files inside backup.backupd?

Tags: macos, backup, time-machine, high-sierra

Suppose if I were to just view my Time Machine backup via Finder and just see its contents, no moving/renaming/deleting. Would just viewing the files affect my Time Machine backup and storing files inside backup.backupd? Because I just created a empty folder inside backup.backupd and I immediately deleted it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's perfectly reasonable to manually navigate your Time Machine backup with Finder, even though you would usually use the Time Machine app instead of Finder. Whilst it's not something to rely on, Finder will prevent you from making changes to a Time Machine backup.

I'd avoid storing your own files in Backups.backupd — put your own files outside this folder, there's no need to put your own files within the backups directory.

Comment: I have edited my question.

Comment: @nobody You can store files there, but why? You've got the rest of the drive to place files, put them elsewhere and leave the backup alone! Edited answer

Comment: Yes I know I should leave the backup folder alone but I am just interested. I am the type of person who likes messing around with system or crucial files. :)

Comment: @nobody That's great and I definitely don't want to you be dissuaded, but it's fine to mess with system files *because* you have a *backup*. When you start messing around with your backup, unless you've got a backup of your backup, you're removing that safety net!

Comment: Yes you are right!